# NSSet setByAddingObjectsFromSet retain count

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, nsset

I thought I was starting to the hang of memory management in objective-c but I'm a little confused by the retain count I'm getting from adding sets together.  The api for setByAddingObjectsFromSet says:

```
Returns a new set formed by adding the objects in a given set to the receiving set.

- (NSSet *)setByAddingObjectsFromSet:(NSSet *)other
```

So I'm a bit puzzled by this:

```
NSSet* tom = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
NSSet* dick = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
NSSet* harry = [tom setByAddingObjectsFromSet:dick];

printf("tom   retainCount: %d \n", [tom retainCount]);
printf("dick  retainCount: %d \n", [dick retainCount]);
printf("harry retainCount: %d \n", [harry retainCount]);
```

Which produces:

```
tom   retainCount: 1 
dick  retainCount: 1 
harry retainCount: 2
```

If setByAddingObjectsFromSet returns a new set why is the retainCount 2?  Do I have to release it twice?!  What have I misunderstood?

Thanks alot.

Comment: Don't use retainCount: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784084/calling-retaincount-considered-harmful

Comment: Also see: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155559/weird-behaviour-with-retaincount) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233143/retaincount-in-blocks-show-extrange-behavior) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483357/nsstring-retaincount-is-2147483647) [4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391479/why-is-the-retaincount-still-1-after-object-release) [5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354724/dont-worry-about-retaincount-really) [6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220902/) [...](http://stackoverflow.com/search?page=3&tab=relevance&q=retaincount)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to release it at all. Actually, you *must not* release it. You don't own it. Those retains are from Cocoa, and it's Cocoa's responsibility to take care of it — they're not your concern. (This is one of the many reasons why looking at `retainCount` is inadvisable.)